# How to get "stringWithFormat" from NSLog() to Variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, nslog

how to get the `stringWithFormat` from `NSLog()` in Swift?

For example the Console Output is `2016-05-24 18:33:31.543 MyPlayground[15578:143357] This is a test!`, so how to get the `2016-05-24 18:33:31.543` or `2016-05-24 18:33:31.543 MyPlayground[15578:143357]` and save it to a Variable, without printing to Console?

Comment: You could make your own Format string to mimic the output: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: I dont understand the question.Can you explain it with some code?

Comment: `String(format:)` is the Swift rendition of Objective-C's `stringWithFormat`.

Comment: Why not hook into the runtime and point the log to a file instead of stdout?  Related discussion: [How to disable logging?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35881034/2415822)

Comment: Do you want to create a string in the same format as NSLog() does (as simpleBob and I thought)? – Or do you want to capture/redirect the NSLog output from your program to a variable? In the latter case, @JAL has pointed to a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers in the square brackets are the process id and the current
thread id, compare e.g. [What are the numbers in the square brackets in NSLog() output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968679/what-are-the-numbers-in-the-square-brackets-in-nslog-output).
The details can be found in the implementation of `__CFLogCString()`
in  http://opensource.apple.com//source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFUtilities.c.

In Swift this can be done as follows:

```
func logstring(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArgType...) -> String {
    let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    let timestamp = fmt.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    let pinfo = NSProcessInfo()
    let pname = pinfo.processName
    let pid = pinfo.processIdentifier
    var tid = UInt64(0)
    pthread_threadid_np(nil, &tid)

    return "\(timestamp) \(pname)[\(pid):\(tid)] " + String(format: format, arguments: arguments)
}
```

Example:

```
NSLog("Hello world, x=%ld", 1234)
// 2016-05-24 19:27:35.282 MyProg[26631:1142252] Hello world, x=1234

print(logstring("Hello world, x=%ld", 1234))
// 2016-05-24 19:27:35.283 MyProg[26631:1142252] Hello world, x=1234
```

Comment: I just wish `print` did that by default, the same as NSLog does. Knowing the time and the thread is useful information!

Comment: nailed it, congrats ;)

Comment: Could you explain, which sense have `format` and `arguments` (parameters given to function)?

Comment: @HelloToYou: `format` is the format and `arguments` a variable arguments list. That are the same parameters that `NSLog()` takes. Compare https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1.

Comment: @MartinR But it is not required, so it's also "okay", if I'm having only one parameter, with the log Statement? And if would like to print a variable, I will just send the var using `"\(TheVar)"` to the function.

Comment: @HelloToYou: `NSLog("some message")` is fine, but string interpolation is dangerous because any percent character is interpreted as a format specifier. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144389/printing-nserror-by-nslog-always-raises-exe-bad-access for an example where this crashes.

Comment: @MartinR What would be, if I'm just having one input argument and replace the return-Statement with `return "\(timestamp) \(pname)[\(pid):\(tid)] \(inputstring)"`?

Comment: @HelloToYou: That's fine.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty close:

```
func interceptLog(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArgType...) -> String {
  let fileName = (#file as NSString).lastPathComponent
  return String(format: "\(NSDate()) \(fileName) [\(#line):\(#column)] \(format)", arguments: arguments)
}
```

While `NSLog("a: %@", "test")` prints:

```
2016-05-24 19:12:35.962 MyPlayground[13970:180094] a: test
```

`print(interceptLog("a: %@", "test"))` would print:

```
2016-05-24 17:17:12 +0000 playground60.swift [7:64] a: test
```